# Question about the proof of the hairy ball theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

> Prove that there exists no nonzero vector field on $S^{2n}$.

If $f: S^{2n} \rightarrow \Bbb R^{2n+1}$ is a nonzero vector field, then $g:S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{2n}$ defined by $x \mapsto f(x) / \|f\|$ is a continuous map with $g(x)$ tangent to $S^{2n}$ at $x$ for every $x$.

This last part is what I'm confused about.  Is it because since the field is nonzero that the inner product $(f(x),x)/\|f\|=0$ iff $x=0$, which is impossible since $0 \notin S^{2n+1}$?

Comment: By the definition of vector field, $f(x)$ is tangent to $\mathbb S^{2n}$ at every $x$. And $g$ is of the same direction as $f$.